# Redundant control flow jump statement

Tags: c#

I am looking through some code. VS marks the return statement as a Redundant control flow jump statement and suggest to remove it. What would be the correct syntax?

```
private async void TokenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var accountType = _settings["account_type"];

            if (accountType.Equals(AccountTypeMicrosoft))
            {
                this.Status.Text += "The original token is good for Live. No new token is needed.\n";
            }
            else
            {
                // Get access token for the target service
                if (!await GetAccessTokenForServiceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Status.Text += "Exception caught: '" + ex.Message + "'.";
            this.Status.Foreground = _errorBrush;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the entire `if` and replace it with:

```
await GetAccessTokenForServiceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true)
```

You don't need to check the result, since the next thing that happens in either case will be the end of the method.

Comment: And remove the whole thing altogether if it is a pure function call

Answer (score 4):

Your function does something like this:

`if (condition)
{
  return;
}
return;`

The return statement is redundant.

Comment: I would note that, if `GetAccessTokenForServiceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true)` had side effects then you would still have to evaluate `condition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the validation condition first and then do the processing like

```
  if (!await GetAccessTokenForServiceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
   {
       return;
   }

    try {
       var accountType = _settings["account_type"];

        if (accountType.Equals(AccountTypeMicrosoft))
        {
            this.Status.Text += "The original ... ";
        }
     }

  catch() {}
```